# Linear independence of a set and its subset

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to ask.

(1) If I have a linearly independent set S with r elements then removing 1 of its elements. Does it make it linearly dependent or independent?

(2) How about the converse? If I have a linearly independent subset A of S, having r-1 elements. Can I conclude that S with r elements is linearly independent?

My idea for (2) is: What if the rth element of S is zero then S is linearly dependent?

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: 1) It becomes "more" linearly independent. 2) you are right.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) the answer is YES an this follows easily from definition.

For 2) the answer is NO. Just add the first of the $r-1$ vectors and the new set becomes linearly dependent.

Comment: The OP's idea of adding the zero vector is even better.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be linearly independent elements of $K$-vector space $V$.
Then
$$k_1v_1+\ldots+k_iv_i+\ldots+k_nv_n=0$$
implies $k_1=\ldots=k_i=\ldots=k_n=0$.

Now consider the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_{i-1},v_{i+1},\ldots,v_n$ by deleting $v_i$.
Then
$$0=k_1v_1+\ldots+k_{i-1}v_{i-1}+k_{i+1}v_{i+1}+\ldots+k_nv_n=k_1v_1+\ldots+k_{i-1}v_{i-1}+0v_i+k_{i+1}v_{i+1}+\ldots+k_nv_n$$
where I have added the term $0v_i$, implies by the linear independence of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ that $k_1=\ldots=k_i=\ldots=k_n=0$.
Thus $v_1,\ldots,v_{i-1},v_{i+1},\ldots,v_n$ is also linearly independent.

(2) as Kavi said. You can easily find an example.